# Manually remove virus/malware that slows down the internet connection

Tags: virus, malware

Is it possible?Or do you know of other ways on how I can remove it. I think the connection has been slowed down. Yesterday, when I download it has 80-100 kbps rate but now its only on 40-50kbps. What do I do with it.

Comment: @user23950: What platform? Windows/Mac OS X/Linux?

Comment: @user23950: how do you know it is a virus?

Comment: @user23950: what kind of connection do you have? ISP, wireless/ADSL/.. What site are you testing the download speed on?

Comment: WINDOWS 7, DSL, SPEEDTEST.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reinstalling, I'd try one or more of the free spyware removal programs. I'm particularly fond of [Spybot Search and Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/) which is a very well known and highly regarded free adware/spyware removal program.

I've also had good luck with the free version of [Lavasoft Ad-Aware](http://www.lavasoft.com/) in the past.

It's important to stick with adware/spyware removal programs that are well established and have a good reputation because occasionally spyware/adware comes disguised as a removal program or a "system cleaner". A lot of these turn out to be just advertisements trying to sell you a sub-par product.

[Hijackthis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) is another free product that can help but it takes a little more care to use. It can make things worse if used to aggressively.

Answer (score 6):

The only sure way to get rid of virus/malware is to reinstall the operating system.

Don't count on being able to do it manually. And it may take longer than reinstalling.

Comment: on top of taking longer, it also isn't fool proof.  and some virus can reinfect your machine before you're done removing it.

Comment: I'll second this. I tried manual removal, then got a BSOD so had to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to anti-virus/reinstalling the OS, you may want to test your connection on another computer.
I've had my actual connection slow down a few times; I ended up having to call the ISP to get it fixed.